# Python error when using open('index.html').read().format()

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pycharm, html-email

I'm trying to generate a dynamic HTML email and send it through a Python script using MIMEMultipart package.

I've created some HTML code and trying to pass in some variables to be used within the HTML from the Python script.

`open('emailContent.html').read().format(p1="help")`

When running this with just basic HTML file (without any CSS) it works and the variable is passed in.

However, when the HTML as a `<style>` tag in the HTML I get the following error:

`KeyError: '\n        fill'`

The HTML file looks something like this:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style type = text/css>

    .chart-text {
        fill: #000;
        -moz-transform: translateY(0.1em);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0.1em);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0.1em);
        transform: translateY(0.1em);
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<p class="chart-text">This is a test please {p1:}
</body>

</html>
```

I'm guessing Python is unable to parse the HTML style tags as when these are removed this works. I need the Styling as this will format the email. Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is happening because `format()` requires that you supply values for all variables found in the string (where "variable" means "anything surrounded by curly braces".)  `\n      fill` happens to be the first token inside the curly braces, and you haven't supplied a value for that token, so it complains.  You get the same error from this much simpler example: `'Hello {x}'.format()`

Comment: The answer might be to avoid using `format()` for strings that can contain arbitrary curly braces.

Comment: I suggest you look into templating engines, like `jinja` or others; `str.format()` is not the right tool for this job because the HTML may contain curly braces that are not meant to be replaced.

Comment: Thank you all, I’ll look into Jinja